# Top bar graphics issues after switching to GNOME Flashback

Tags: gnome-classic, ubuntu-gnome

I recently installed ubuntu-gnome-flashback on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and after logging in to GNOME Flashback (Compiz), my top bar, menu, and windows look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMIzm.jpg).

This is not the standard GNOME2 look that I'm supposed to get (which should look something like [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/ubuntu-classic-desktop.jpg)), so I'm not sure what's going on.  Moreover, I now get the same weird graphics in the top panel if I switch back to the default Unity desktop.  What's going on, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In first screenshoot you are using Adwaita theme. In second screenshoot Ambiance theme is used.

Install gnome-tweak-tool, there will be option to change theme.